# XPath containing Math Expressions

Tags: c#, xpath, linq-to-xml

The following line:

```
string cellData = d.XPathSelectElement(cellSelector).Value;
```

Throws an exception stating "The XPath expression evaluated to unexpected type System.Double."

The CellSelector contains: "./Units * ./product/Cost"

The Data in XElement d is:

```
<LineItem>
  <product>
    <ProductId>22</ProductId>
    <ProductName>Car Cleaning</ProductName>
    <Cost>26.02</Cost>
  </product>
  <Units>2</Units>
</LineItem>
```

In this example, I need the output of that line to be "52.04" and even more ideally, I'd love it to be "£ 52.04".

What would the XPathExpression have to look like to accomplish that?

I tried changing the expression to "String(./Units * ./product/Cost)" but that generates the exception "The XPath expression evaluated to unexpected type System.String." which I would expect to have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`XPathEvaluate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341675) seems to be what you want:

```
var cellData = xml.XPathEvaluate("./Units * ./product/Cost");
cellData = string.Format("£ {0}", cellData);
// result: cellData == "£ 52,04"
```

Answer (score 2):

**[`XPathSelectElement(expr)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351355.aspx) expects the result of evaluation of the XPath expression `expr` to be an element** (as the name of the method shows).

**In your case you need to use another method, that allows *any* XPath expression** (not only an expression selecting an element) as argument.

**[`XPathEvaluate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341675.aspx)** is such a method.